# Create a custom table with select statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, select

I have been wondering how can I create a table with multiple rows via this.

```
select 'lol' as foo, 'rofl' as new
```

Because the above statement create 2 columns and 1 row. But how can I create, say, 5 custom rows in the table columns?
I need to do that with a select statement to test stuff, not using create table, update etc. statement that actually create 'physical' tables.
Sorry if it's such a noob question, but I haven't found an answer in the MySQL documentation. There's a [row()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/row-subqueries.html), but it applies to rows and it doesn't seem to fit into my undertaking. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION:

```
SELECT 'lol' as foo, 'rofl' as new
UNION ALL
SELECT 'lol2' as foo, 'rofl2' as new
```

Comment: Is that the only way or is it possible to write something like `select col('a','b','c') as one, col('d','e','f') as two`

Comment: It's the first valid way I thought of. Usually in computing you can have more than one solution to a problem. Yours isn't valid BTW.

Comment: I know that mine isn't valid. It's an 'imaginary' code example to get my point across. I was asking if there's another, more compact solution. I haven't found anything, hence, am asking.